# What is generic point of (0, 1] mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, terminology

I read "Probability and Measure". In first page of chapter 1, I had a problem about what is generic point of $(0, 1]$? Could everyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Could you show somewhere $\omega$ is used?

Comment: It means that $\omega$ is a symbol which denotes any element of the set $(0;1]$

Comment: @Karl yes, I saw in wikipedia but i can't understand

Comment: @Crostul Oh! Tks!!!